# open Navigation Drawer by click on top left icon

Tags: android

I create a BaseActivity and extend other activities from it so the navigation appears on all activities well

now i want to show an icon on the top left like google play app when the user clicks on it it open the side menu

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863925/android-open-navigation-drawer-by-clicking-the-app-icon

Comment: where i should write this on the base class  or extended one

Comment: If the base `Activity` contains the `DrawerLayout`, then put it there.

Comment: ok you mean i should write it on onOptionsItemSelected or setContentView or onCreate of the base class